# parted command (start and end meaning)

Tags: partition, disk, parted

I am using the Linux `parted` command; I was using the 'mkpart' option which allows new partitions to be made, but I was confused when it asked me for the **start** and **end**.

What does 'start' and 'end' mean when talking about disks?

What's the need and use for a start and end?

Comment: The manual isn't clear about these parameters.

Answer (score 6):

This is to define the size of your partition and where it starts/end. If you want to have only one big partition, give 0% for start and 100% for end. Then for multiple partitions you can play with percents or sectors.

For instance if you want to split your disk in 2 partitions

- 0% 50% for the first one
- 50% 100% for the 2nd

should make the job

Comment: when i do 0% 50% - i see there is start at `1049kB` and free space bettween 17.4kB and 1049kB. Why it happens?

Comment: Note "0" and "0%" are not the same thing in parted. 0 and 100% gave me a warning about performance problems with partition size but 0% and 100% worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

From the users manual for [GNU parted](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html#mkpart):

> *start* and *end* are the offset from the beginning of the disk, that is, the “distance” from the start of the disk.

This is also implied if not outright explained when you `print` the current partition table in the parted interface. Check the column heads in the table:

```
(parted) print
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 53.7GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1075MB  1074MB  primary  ext4         boot
 2      1075MB  53.7GB  52.6GB  primary               lvm
```

The *start* value indicates where you want the new partition to begin. It can be specified in several ways -- an absolute value for size/space, a percentage of the disk size, etc. -- and is measured from the beginning of the disk.

Comment: ok i see, so could you give me an example of how i could calculate the start and end for a partition of 2GB?